# Using promise to call Ajax without duplicating code

Tags: javascript, ajax, es6-promise

is this possible? I want to write an ajax function, that I do not want to duplicate it. Pass it different parameter which are locations to different files. Then use the promise to make them into one object. I would possible use the spread operator. is this possible.

```
var myFuncCalls = 0;

let promiseAjax = new Promise (function ( resolve,reject) {

//possibly use a for look to grab the number of times the loadDoc was called then call the same function and send it to may be an array?
    function loadDoc(location) {
        myFuncCalls++;
        console.log("loadDoc was called :" + myFuncCalls);



        var xyz = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xyz.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //console.log(this.responseText)
                resolve(this.responseText);          
            }
        };

        xyz.open("GET", location, true);
        xyz.send();
    }

    loadDoc("/_js/someitems.json");
    loadDoc("/_js/someMoreItems.json");
})

// then grab all that stuff and make one single object using spread operators
promiseAjax.then(function (fromResolve){

    // JSON.parse(fromResolve);
    var newObj = JSON.parse(fromResolve);
    console.log(newObj);

})
```

Comment: What kind of backwards compatibility do you need? Could you use the promise-based [`fetch`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) instead?

Comment: hello, right now there's no need for compatibility. I'm trying to avoid duplication of code.... BUT you bring up an interesting point, I wasn't aware there could be compatibility issues.

Comment: `Promise.all()`

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to me. You want a function that you can pass an array of file names, and it does some async stuff and returns back to you... what exactly? Can you try to be more specific

Comment: Fetch has [very good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) cross-browser support, but if you need 100%, it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Hi @TKoL yes I want to pass several files names to a function with an ajax call then get the object back as a resolve, then combine them.. fornow ignore that i want to combine them. and just want one function to be able to handle multiples files

Comment: One other thing that I think is worth mentioning is that if you're requesting multiple JSON files and combining them on the client side, your greatest area for improvement might be the server, so the client can receive all that data in one request rather than many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `Promise.all` and `Object.assign`,

```
function loadDoc(location) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xyz = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xyz.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else {
        // resolving with empty object to avoid breaking other fetch if one failed
        resolve({});
      }
    };

    xyz.open("GET", location, true);
    xyz.send();
  });
}

const loadDocs = (paths) => Promise.all(paths.map(path => loadDoc(path))
  .then(results => {
    // combine all result into single object
    return Object.assign({}, ...results);
  }));

// example
loadDocs([
  "/_js/someitems.json",
  "/_js/someMoreItems.json"
]).then(function(finalCombinedObject) {
  // other logic here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Promise.all() to get the two calls together and so what ever you want with the array of the data you resolved.

```
function loadDoc(location) {
  return new Promise (function ( resolve,reject) {
    var xyz = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xyz.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        resolve(this.responseText);          
      }
    };
    xyz.open("GET", location, true);
    xyz.send();
  });
}

const urls = ["/_js/someitems.json", "/_js/someMoreItems.json"]
Promise.all(urls.map(url=>loadDoc(url))).then(responses =>
  console.log(responses);
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing would be to define async functions, which return promises and can be easily passed around and reused.

You can do something like:

```
async function loadFile(file) {
   ...
   return {...fileJSON};
}

async function loadFiles() {
    const file1JSON = await loadFile('file1');
    const file2JSON = await loadFile('file2');
    return {...file1JSON, ...file2JSON};
}

loadFiles().then((combinedJSON) => {
  ...
})
```

These functions can take arguments and be reused like any other function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, youcan send the URL, any parameters, even the type of AJAX call (POST, GET, etc), to the method, then use it to build the call. This way, you can reuse the same method to do anything and everything you need to do from your client with a "simple" method call.

All code in this Answer is copied from the below link.

> https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/ajax-async-callback-promise-e98f8074ebd7

```
function makeAjaxCall(url, methodType)
{
 var promiseObj = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
 {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(methodType, url, true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4)
   {
    if (xhr.status === 200)
    {
     console.log("xhr done successfully");
     var resp = xhr.responseText;
     var respJson = JSON.parse(resp);
     resolve(respJson);
    }
    else
    {
     reject(xhr.status);
     console.log("xhr failed");
    }
   }
   else {console.log('xhr processing going on');}
  }
  console.log("request sent succesfully");
 });
 return promiseObj;
}
enter code here
document.getElementById('userDetails').addEventListener('click', function()
{
 // git hub url to get btford details
 var userId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
 var URL = "https://api.github.com/users/"+userId;
 makeAjaxCall(URL, "GET").then(processUserDetailsResponse, errorHandler);
});
```

You can even send it the callback method. I also send it a method to use for errors.

```
function makeAjaxCall(url, methodType, callback)
{
  $.ajax(
  {
   url : url,
   method : methodType,
   dataType : "json",
   success : callback,
   error : function (reason, xhr){
   console.log("error in processing your request", reason);
  }
 });
}
// git hub url to get btford details
var URL = "https://api.github.com/users/btford";
makeAjaxCall(URL, "GET", function(respJson)
{
 document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML = respJson.login;
 document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = respJson.name;
 document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = respJson.company;
 document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = respJson.blog;
 document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = respJson.location;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of behavior can archived with `Promise.all` [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) white the use of `async`+`await` [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and the use of more state of the art calls (`fetch`) makes the code looks cleaner

```
async function loadAll(docs) {
    return Promise.all(docs.map(async doc => {
        const result = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
        return result.json();
    }));
}

(async function() {
    const responses = await loadAll(["/_js/someitems.json", "/_js/someMoreItems.json"]);
    console.log(responses);
})();
```

Note: await can only be used from an async function.
Note2: the code is untested